# Fix status bar and layout with list view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-recyclerview

I have a list view inside of `CoordinatorLayout` with `ActionBar`. I'm not sure if I got everything right, but the top is looking strange. What am I doing wrong here? I've been fiddling with the XML for a long while and can't get it right :(

Notice the top:

[image]

This is my activity layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RecyclerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:text="@string/empty_notifications" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my recycler view item layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Example application"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there a better way to do this or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I already had some issues with the `CoordinatorLayout` and in your case I think you should use `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in the `Layout` below your `AppBarLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        ...>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        ...
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Good try but the status bar remains the same :(

Answer (score 1):

I added `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to my `CoordinatorLayout` and it worked!